# JavaFX - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when executing WebView exemple code

Tags: javafx, error-handling, webview

I tried to run an example of WebView project and I had this error

```
C:\Users\Dell\.jdks\openjdk-19.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=50766:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\javafx-dialogs-0.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\icepdf\os\icepdf-viewer\6.1.2\icepdf-viewer-6.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\icepdf\os\icepdf-core\6.1.2\icepdf-core-6.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.54\bcprov-jdk15on-1.54.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-ext-jdk15on\1.54\bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.54.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.54\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.54.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\javax\media\jai-core\1.1.3\jai-core-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\com\sun\media\jai_imageio\1.1\jai_imageio-1.1.pom;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\batik\batik-awt-util\1.6\batik-awt-util-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\batik\batik-dom\1.6\batik-dom-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\batik\batik-svg-dom\1.6\batik-svg-dom-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\batik\batik-svggen\1.6\batik-svggen-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\batik\batik-util\1.6\batik-util-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\batik\batik-xml\1.6\batik-xml-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\jfxcore\javafx-media\18-ea+1\javafx-media-18-ea+1.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\jfxcore\javafx-graphics\18-ea+1\javafx-graphics-18-ea+1.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\jfxcore\javafx-base\18-ea+1\javafx-base-18-ea+1.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jetty\websocket\websocket-api\9.4.46.v20220331\websocket-api-9.4.46.v20220331.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\webjars\webjars-locator\0.30\webjars-locator-0.30.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\webjars\webjars-locator-core\0.30\webjars-locator-core-0.30.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.9\commons-compress-1.9.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.3.3\jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.3.0\jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.3.3\jackson-core-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.4\commons-lang3-3.4.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\19-ea+7\javafx-controls-19-ea+7.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\19-ea+7\javafx-graphics-19-ea+7.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\19-ea+7\javafx-base-19-ea+7.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\19-ea+7\javafx-fxml-19-ea+7.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\19-ea+7\javafx-web-19-ea+7.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\19-ea+7\javafx-media-19-ea+7.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\net\synedra\validatorfx\0.3.1\validatorfx-0.3.1.jar -p "C:\Users\Dell\IdeaProjects\PFEL\target\classes;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\19-ea+7\javafx-web-19-ea+7-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\19-ea+7\javafx-fxml-19-ea+7-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\bootstrapfx\bootstrapfx-core\0.4.0\bootstrapfx-core-0.4.0.jar;D:\MI\3LMD\memoire\Nouveau dossier\JavaFxLibs\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\19-ea+7\javafx-controls-19-ea+7-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-javafx\12.3.1\ikonli-javafx-12.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-core\12.3.1\ikonli-core-12.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\jfxcore\javafx-graphics\18-ea+1\javafx-graphics-18-ea+1-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\19-ea+7\javafx-graphics-19-ea+7-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\jfxcore\javafx-media\18-ea+1\javafx-media-18-ea+1-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\19-ea+7\javafx-media-19-ea+7-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\formsfx\formsfx-core\11.5.0\formsfx-core-11.5.0.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\jfxcore\javafx-base\18-ea+1\javafx-base-18-ea+1-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\19-ea+7\javafx-base-19-ea+7-win.jar;C:\Users\Dell\.m2\repository\org\controlsfx\controlsfx\11.1.1\controlsfx-11.1.1.jar" -m com.example.pfel/com.example.pfel.Elearning
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Dell/IdeaProjects/PFEL/target/classes/com/example/pfel/Html.fxml:11

    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at com.example.pfel/com.example.pfel.Elearning.start(Elearning.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:497)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:470)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:469)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18-ea/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:180)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory$ObjectBuilderWrapper$ObjectBuilder.build(JavaFXBuilderFactory.java:237)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:774)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2924)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2639)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory$ObjectBuilderWrapper$ObjectBuilder.build(JavaFXBuilderFactory.java:229)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet()'
    at javafx.controls@19-ea/javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:99)
    at javafx.web@19-ea/com.sun.javafx.webkit.theme.ScrollBarThemeImpl$1.invalidated(ScrollBarThemeImpl.java:84)
    at javafx.base@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:348)
    at javafx.base@18-ea/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18-ea/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ObjectPropertyBase.java:106)
    at javafx.base@18-ea/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.base@18-ea/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.base@18-ea/javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.setValue(ObjectProperty.java:78)
    at javafx.web@19-ea/javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.setView(WebEngine.java:997)
    at javafx.web@19-ea/javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:276)
    at javafx.web@19-ea/com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.web.WebViewBuilder.build(WebViewBuilder.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application com.example.pfel.Elearning

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and this is the fxml file and the controller

FXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.pfel.Html">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webview" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="4.0" prefHeight="333.0" prefWidth="590.0" />
      <Button layoutX="27.0" layoutY="361.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadpage" text="load" />
      <TextField fx:id="textfield" layoutX="145.0" layoutY="361.0" onAction="#loadpage" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller:

```java
package com.example.pfel;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Html implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private WebView webview;
    @FXML
    private TextField textfield;
    private WebEngine engine;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        engine = webview.getEngine();
        loadpage();
    }
    public void loadpage(){

    }

}
```

Comment: You're using different versions of JavaFX modules/dependencies. The stack trace shows you using `19-ea` for `javafx.web`, `javafx.controls`, and `javafx.fxml` but that you're using `18-ea` for `javafx.base` and `javafx.graphics`. Make sure you're using the same version for each JavaFX module/dependency. Also, it is unlikely you need an `ea` version (stands for "early access"). The latest stable release is `19`.

Comment: How can i use javafx.base and javafx.graphics 19 ?

Comment: @siradj_ben: Please [edit] your question about how you build and run.

Comment: @siradj_ben That would depend on how you're declaring a dependency on JavaFX. I recommend reading [Getting Started with JavaFX 11+](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for your chosen IDE and build tool (if any). Then simply configure your project to use version 19 of JavaFX.